# Why does separation of variables work in the Schrodinger equation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation

Explain why after assuming separable solution, we equate the time dependent function and the position dependent functions to a constant $E$.

Specifically, why should it be a constant and why not some random function of $t$ or $x$?

If it were a function of $x$, would we not equate the $\psi(x)$ to that function, get $\psi$ and then decide $\phi(t)$?

Comment: Please read our [FAQ on writing good titles](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6413/how-do-we-write-good-question-titles). I have edited the title of this post to be more descriptive. Also please define all variables used in the question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its a pure math question. I do not think it should be migrated though, because it uses several variables without defining them, and as such needs clarification before it would be suitable to migrate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say that you have two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. Also suppose that we have \begin{equation}
f(x_1) = g(x_2)
\end{equation} for all values of $x_1$ and $x_2$. Then there is a number $A$ such that $g(2)=A$. Since the above equation is valid for all $x_2$, in particular it is valid for $x_2=2$. Then we deduce $$f(x_1) = A$$ for all values of $x_1$, in other words $f$ is a constant function. It is immediate that $g$ is also constant.

Comment: You mean g(x2) not g(2) right?

Comment: I actually mean $2$ as in the result of $1+1$. I can do that because the first equation is valid for all values of $x_2$, so I choose one.

Comment: Oh right. I got it.

Comment: I edited the question so it's more obvious